# how select element generated by script selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I need to choose element **APPLICATION** from list on UI. html code of this element (in html I have 10 such elements)is:

```
<tr id="4676856" class="menuItem" orientation="vertical" collectionid="tr4" radioid="12">
<td id="ItemL" class="left" data-click="[["runScript",["switchApplication('myapp')"]]]" data-ctl="nav">
<div class="menuRB"/>
</td>
<td id="ItemM" class="middleBack" tabindex="0" data-click="[["runScript",["switchApplication('myapp')"]]]"     data-ctl="nav">**APPLICATION**</td>
<td id="ItemR" class="rightEdge" data-click="[["runScript",["switchApplication('myapp')"]]]" data-ctl="nav"/>
```

I have never worked with such script, how can I find such element using selenium webdriver?

I have tried

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen0']/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: Post your question with clear code and example.

Answer (score 1):

Please show HTML code that matches your XPaths (where is `yui-gen0` and such?)

From the info you provided, few issues you might want to avoid:

- Try avoid using div[6], tr[12], use meaningful things instead of index
- Don't use `yui-gen0` if it's auto-generated
- Keep HTML ids unique, like `id="ItemM"`. If they are unique, use them directly

I'd suggest try the following (we need you to show more HTML in order to avoid using div[6], tr[12]):

```
// find by text '**APPLICATION**'
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen0']/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[text()='**APPLICATION**']")).click();

// find by class name (if it's the only one)
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen0']/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[@class='middleBack']")).click();

// find by class name (if there are others)
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='yui-gen0']/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[12]/td[contains(@class, 'middleBack')]")).click();

// find by id, which should be unique, if it's not, your HTML is bad
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ItemM']")).click();
```

Comment: @khris: Do you have any feedback on this? Did it work for you?